# How to obtain Background color of a button with drawable state?

Tags: java, android

Here is my drawable state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffdcd400" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#ffe8e000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I get the button with this function:

```
public void ir(View v)
{
        Button boton_clickeado=(Button)v;
        StateListDrawable drawable= (StateListDrawable) v.getBackground();
}
```

I want to get the background color (state not pressed) "#ffe8e000" programmatically.
But I don't know which function use to obtain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

`int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
StateListDrawable drawable= (StateListDrawable) v.getBackground();
if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable)
color = ((ColorDrawable) drawable).getColor();`

Comment: getting err msg from Android Studio about those two types being inconvertible :(